openssl version returns "libssl.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory" after compiling openssl
Here's what I tried:
wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-3.3.0.tar.gz
tar xvzf openssl-3.3.0.tar.gz
cd openssl-3.3.0
./config
make
make install

When I type in openssl version after that I get this:
openssl: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I didn't see any errors during any of the above steps.
Any ideas?

There is a detailed description of this problem in the files NOTES-UNIX.md which came with your OpenSSL download. See the section "Shared libraries and installation in non-default locations":
https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/openssl-3.3/NOTES-UNIX.md
In short the simplest solution is to add '-Wl,-rpath,$(LIBRPATH)' (for Linux type platforms) onto your config command line. See the above file for other platform variants. If reusing the same download location be sure to make clean first:
make clean
./config '-Wl,-rpath,$(LIBRPATH)'
make
make install

